# Unable to apply routing to orders page

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I have the following routes, one for the account landing page and one for the account orders page. The first route would great, it lands on the page and I can apply the unique page structure I require but no matter what configuration I try I can't seem to get anything to apply to the orders page, or the individual order page for that matter.

In an ideal world it would also use the the pageLabel **account-orders**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'my-account',
    component: AccountOverviewPageComponent,
    canActivate: [CmsPageGuard],
    data: {
      pageLabel: 'account-overview'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'my-account/orders',
    component: AccountOrdersPageComponent,
    canActivate: [CmsPageGuard],
    data: {
      pageLabel: 'my-account/orders'
    }
  }
])
```

I have also tried the following configuration. Mimicing the configuration from the @spartacus files

```
{
  // @ts-ignore
  path: null,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard, CmsPageGuard],
  component: AccountOrdersPageComponent,
  data: { cxRoute: 'orders' },
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've had no luck with this.

**Define "I can't seem to get anything to apply to the orders page" please**

When I apply this block, all it ever does it did before. It does a lookup for "my-account/orders" and then redirects to the generic **pagetemplatecomponent** not my **AccountOrdersPageComponent**. Everything I've tried always leads down this route.

Comment: Define "I can't seem to get anything to apply to the orders page" please

Comment: could you try to change the order of these routes? so the longer one would go first

Comment: I've tried running them both exclusively, but it didn't make a difference sadly.